# iOS - Screen Transition without IBAction

Tags: objective-c, ios5

I am trying to figure out how to change screens without having to call IBAction.

So for example I have two screens as follows,

1 - Counting down

2 - Counting down over.

First I am on screen 1 and, as I finish counting down in that view, I want to transition to screen 2.

So here I am not calling IBAction. I just want to move to another screen by calling some kind of a function. How do I do that?

(Environment - iOS 5.1)

Comment: IBAction is just a function triggered by some event. You can also call function you need directly. 
What kind of IBAction do you use now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create two `UIViewControllers` for both of your screens and create `UIStoryboardSegue` object to move between them:

```
 (id)initWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier source:(UIViewController *)source destination:(UIViewController *)destination
```

Reference:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider accepting this answer by checking green tick ;)